# Does Google provide enough CC-BY-SA attribution?

Tags: discussion, licensing

First of all, I'm impressed by Google again. Somehow they managed to extract relevant parts of an answer into a immediate result when I [search for Java Home (Google Germany)](https://www.google.de/search?q=JAVA+HOME):

[image: Google Search Result]

While it links to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7), the box is mainly filled with content of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142065/4136325).

But note, that the extracted part isn't identical. It has

- added "your desktop" in step 2
- removed "on the left side of your screen" in step 3
- corrected a spelling mistake in step 3
- ...

Modifying an answer like this is allowed by CC-BA-SA license, but shouldn't Google give credits to the author, [Ankit jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201371/ankit-jain) in this case?

Comment: You are not the first one to bring this up.  SE doesn't seem very interested in fixing this, somebody has to hire his own lawyer.  Google will probably mumble something like "fair use" and that will be the end of it.  Them rulez just don't apply to the big boys.

Comment: Actually, the text appears to have come from a [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6521412/1) of the top-voted answer. Only the photo is from the answer you linked.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't see how adding hyperlinked \@question_author, \@answer_author would make the web a better place here. Google is a search engine: the screenshot demonstrates that it does an *outstanding* job here: relevant link + smart excerpt. It doesn't make sense to add attribution other than the corresponding links on the SERP.

Comment: I can't replicate your google search experience. Have they already removed the feature? Could you post a link with your google search, that lead to the smart excerpt ?

Comment: Throw this question into the feedback link there, it's probably helpful to someone there.

Comment: What about the missing up/down voting buttons? Are the authors potentially losing upvotes this way? Or would that be favoring the top rated / Google chosen answer too much and putting the others at disadvantage? It would seem that it will skew the counters of people who viewed the question / answer (the "people reached" value in the profile).

Comment: "SE doesn't seem very interested in fixing this" - Why would they be?  I'm sure Google would be happy to refrain from crawling SE sites if SE were to insist on fixing this "problem" (either directly or by setting up the appropriate `robots.txt` directives).  But who would that actually serve?  Basically nobody.  I think what you actually have is an implicit license between SE and Google; one where Google says "let us index your content and we'll send you absurd amounts of traffic", and SE says "yes, please do".

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: Perhaps it's related to Google Germany. I added the link to the question.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Nice finding. Maybe Google is not so clever as I thought

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IANAL, but Google appear to be in the clear.

The key point is, CC attribution clauses can be met **by reasonable means according to the medium**. It does not require blind adherence to the requests of the licensor. SE can say whatever it wants in its [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), but that doesn't mean every point must be met or that every point is reasonable for all media.

For [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/legalcode), the relevant clause is 4(c):

> If You distribute, publicly display, publicly perform, or publicly digitally perform the Work (as defined in Section 1 above) or any Derivative Works (as defined in Section 1 above) or Collective Works (as defined in Section 1 above), You must, unless a request has been made pursuant to Section 4(a), keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and provide, **reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing**: (i) the name of the Original Author (or pseudonym, if applicable) if supplied, and/or (ii) if the Original Author and/or Licensor designate another party or parties (e.g. a sponsor institute, publishing entity, journal) for attribution ("Attribution Parties") in Licensor's copyright notice, terms of service or by other reasonable means, the name of such party or parties; the title of the Work if supplied; to the extent reasonably practicable, the Uniform Resource Identifier, if any, that Licensor specifies to be associated with the Work, unless such URI does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work; and, consistent with Section 3(b) in the case of a Derivative Work, a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Derivative Work (e.g., "French translation of the Work by Original Author," or "Screenplay based on original Work by Original Author"). **The credit required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable manner**; provided, however, that in the case of a Derivative Work or Collective Work, at a minimum such credit will appear, if a credit for all contributing authors of the Derivative Work or Collective Work appears, then as part of these credits and in a manner at least as prominent as the credits for the other contributing authors. For the avoidance of doubt, You may only use the credit required by this Section for the purpose of attribution in the manner set out above and, by exercising Your rights under this License, You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties.

What exactly does "reasonable" mean? [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode) contains clearer language, in section 3(a)(2):

> You may satisfy the conditions in Section 3(a)(1) **in any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context** in which You Share the Licensed Material. For example, it may be reasonable to satisfy the conditions by **providing a URI or hyperlink to a resource that includes the required information**.

Is simply providing a link to SE "reasonable"? That's for a court to decide, *not* whatever SE dictates. Sure they can send [DMCA takedowns](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/) to bully scraper sites, even the ones that link back to SE, but against Google who are most likely willing to take it to court? Good luck with that.

Answer (score 31):

No. Google is not meeting the requirements of the license, which [requires](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn't have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
3. Show the author names for every question and answer
4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Google is failing on points 3 and 4.

Comment: They also fail on this one: *By "directly", I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.*

Comment: I'm not sure if https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ matters, since it's not part of the actual CC-BY-SA 3.0 license. Still the license requires the name of the author [clause 4c (i)] which google does not provide.

Comment: I think this misses the point of whether it even _matters_ if Google strictly follows the license terms or not.  Everyone knows what Google does, and there's a clear and well-documented process for opting out (via `robots.txt` directives) for any organization that's not okay with it.  In essence Google only goes where it's invited to go, so I'd suggest that if this actually mattered SE would have already taken action by opting out.  Clearly (and I think, rightly) they'd rather take the free advertising/traffic from Google than get pedantic over licensing technicalities.

Comment: There is no "geting pedantic over licensing technicalities", you either respect a license or you don't.

Comment: @aroth: It's great and all that Google has monopoly powers that allow it to bully others into not pressing their legal rights, but strictly speaking, cutting off all indexing is not the only remedy. SE could, one supposes, actually sue them if needed for breach of license. The only real reasons not to are cost of pursuing the suit, and the possible backlash from Google "forgetting" that SE pages have such a high PageRank.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Additional reasons not to could also be the possibility of losing the suit due to a successful 'Fair Use' defense (which may also result in SE being forced to pay Google's legal costs), and also the difficulty of proving that any damages have actually occurred as a result of the breach (which could limit recompense even if the suit succeeds).  In essence, the status-quo works better for everyone involved.  Particularly so far as legal action is concerned...the only people who definitely win in that scenario are the lawyers.

Answer (score 4):

According to @ughoavgfhw, the text in the steps was not actually modified. It came from a [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6521412/1) of the answer.

Also, building on @TZHX's answer, I don't think Google needs to display, or link, authors' names to their profiles because once a user clicks the link in the search result, they are taken to the Stack Overflow page where the usernames are listed and linked to their profile. So technically, Google is hitting the last three of @TZHX's points with one link to the question.

Comment: Your second paragraph is utter nonsense. The license regulates **all** use of the content. Google is making use of the content and thus **it** must follow the rules. A link to the question **is not enough**, period.

Comment: @Bakuriu "Fair use" doesn't require you to comply with the license, but comes with its own set of limitations. I wouldn't want to argue in court against google's lawyers that what they're doing isn't covered by fair use.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I don't see what the license has to do with the SERP results. If you don't want the pages to be indexed by google; there are other tools such as `robots.txt`.